# How to set device volume with Slider in Flutter

Tags: flutter

As the title says, how to adjust device volume in Flutter? I want to use a Slider to adjust the device volume, but I didn't find a way.

Comment: you can use volume 0.1.0 package , we have functions and getter's to control the Volume https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/volume . you can browse the above link

Comment: got it, thanks! : )

Answer (score 1):

I put my simple code here.

I tested on a pixel 3a API 27.(According to the package, 'No IOS Implementation yet.')

Later, I am going to changed the fixed max-value of slider with a value gotten from `Volume.getMaxVol`, and initial slider value with `Volume.getVol`.

```
import 'package:volume/volume.dart';
...

class _PlayerState extends State<Player> {
    double _sliderValue = 0.0;
    int maxVol, currentVol;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initPlatformState();
    }

    Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
        await Volume.controlVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); // you can change which volume you want to change.
    }

    updateVolumes() async {
        maxVol = await Volume.getMaxVol;
        currentVol = await Volume.getVol;
        setState(() {});
    }

    setVol(int i) async {
        await Volume.setVol(i);
    }


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Slider(
        activeColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
        min: 0.0,
        max: 15.0,
        onChanged: (newRating) async {
            setState(() {
                sliderValue = newRating;
            });
            await setVol(newRating.toInt());
            await updateVolumes();
        },
        value: _sliderValue,
    )
}
```